# Can authentication be enabled for Command Line and Powershell access on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, command-line, authentication

I want to avoid the possibility of a malicious USB device creating an unexpected keyboard HID, opening a command shell, and running commands.

One possibility would to force authentication before opening a command window.

Is it possible to configure Windows 10 so that it requests a password when the user attempts to open a Command Prompt or Powershell window?

Comment: The question not way to prevent what you want is to implement a group policy that only allows specific USB devices.  However, as someone who had to work on a server where that policy was initially implemented, it’s a major pain in the rear and limited to around 15 devices  in total. You can disable the command prompt and PowerShell with a group policy.

Comment: Keep in mind that depending on your approach running a .bat or .ps1 might still work even when the regular access to cmd/powershell are "blocked".